# how to set This in element input without tagging ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

5 input type, without tagging ID's; if I click the input prompt command will appear and say enter your name?; after entering the name how can I codes the jquery of "This.value = person"...

```
<div class="lines">
            <input type="text"><span>7-5</span></input>
            <input type="text"><span>7-6</span></input>
            <input type="text"><span>7-7</span></input>
            <input type="text"><span>7-8</span></input>
            <input type="text"><span>7-9</span></input>
</div>
```

then my Jquery are

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
var elementThis = $("input").click(function(){

 var person = prompt("Please enter your name:");

    if (person != null) {
        this['input'] = person;   
    } 

    $(this).css("background-color","green");
});
});
```

please help. They didn't input the person = prompt on the clickable inputs.

Comment: `</input>`? Input is one of the Void Elements and cannot have a closing tag. (Neither can contain other child elements)

Answer (score 1):

Well a slight modification here

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bj3pyqqu/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("input").click(function(){
        var that=$(this);//create a reference
        var person = prompt("Please enter your name:");
        if (person) { //as per @Roko C.Buljan's suggestion
           that.val(person);   //assign its val
           //or even $(this) is fine
           that.css("background-color","green");//as per @Roko C.Buljan's suggestion
           //You can move it here in case cancel is clicked
        } 
    });
});
```

**[Cancel validation demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bj3pyqqu/1/)**

and yea no `</input>` as @Roko C.Buljan said. `<input>` cannot have closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

just use the .val() function to set the current element value property

```
$(this).val(person);
```

and remove `</input>` its not needed

Comment: Thank You Guys...

$(this).val(person); makes my Day happy :)